# Manage link in a partial file in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In one of my application I have multiple scopes (**admin, trader, manager, seller)**

In each scope, I'd like to show the same page (**exemple : show a seller**) but in this page I've got link to edit the seller :

```
 - admin_edit_seller_path(@seller)
 - trader_edit_seller_path(@seller)
```

The page is exactly the same except for the link.
How can i manage that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case you can use Rails' [Polymorphic Routes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html)

For example:

```
new_polymorphic_path(@manager)              # => "/managers/new"
edit_polymorphic_path(@seller)              # => "/sellers/1/edit"
polymorphic_path(@trader, format: :json)    # => "/traders/1.json"
```

Or in your case, with scopes, you could use this form:

```
edit_polymorphic_path([:admin, seller])  # => "http://example.com/admin/sellers
polymorphic_path([:trader, seller]) # => "http://example.com/trader/sellers
```

Which means you can use this in a view:

```
   <%= render partial: 'shared/my_partial', locals: {scope: :admin, object: @seller} %>
```

And this in your partial:

```
   <%= link_to edit_polymorphic_path([scope, object]), [scope, object] %>
```

Comment: Awesome! This is a great approach for DRYing up some code!